# Formulation: Smooth vs. finitely often differentiable

Tags: notation, article-writing

I treat the cases $f\in C^\infty$ and $f\in C^k$ in different sections of my thesis. While I am happy with the title *smooth functions* for the first section, I am not so sure if *finitely often differentiable functions* for the second is idiomatic.

Comment: How about just *"$C^k$ functions"*?

Comment: *Finitely differentiable* sounds a lot less confusing than *finitely often differentiable*

Comment: @Zev: is it common to use formulas in section titles? i admit i like *$C^\infty$ functions* vs. *$C^k$ functions*

Comment: I would find "finitely (blah) functions" jarring, but "$C^k$ functions" not so.

Comment: @Bananach you should avoid it. However, short and well known formula should be okay. The term "finitely often differentiable  functions" is used pretty rarely.

Comment: thanks all. i guess i will just merge the sections and make the jump clear by prosa.